# LTC3780 for charging batteries (backflow protection)

Tags: diodes, schottky

I have very little experience with these type of things and I couldn't find the answer anywhere else. I want to use [LTC3780](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3780ff.pdf) module with ATX PSU to primarily charge batteries (deep cycle battery and maybe lead acid batteries).

In the description it says that it does not have backflow protection. I assume if I were to charge batteries and then disconnect module from the input voltage, battery would kill the module? To prevent this I should use Schottky diode.

There are diodes like [20SQ045](http://www.smc-diodes.com/propdf/20SQ045%20N0006%20REV.B.pdf) which are rated at 45 V 20 A and would be more than enough, but in the description it says to use diodes in series? Can someone help me and tell me what diodes should I use? Do I really have to use more than 1? I am aware that more powerful diodes have a higher current leakage but how much is too much?

Comment: You should add links to the datasheets for the LTC3780 and 20SQ045 so people can help you.  I assume by series, they mean as opposed to parallel, not that you need more than one.

Comment: Hey @evildemonic thanks for the reply, data sheets were added by Greenonline thanks to him. So do you think 20SQ045 is enough or maybe too much ? Should i use weaker ones ?